# AS3 Custom contextMenu to children

Tags: actionscript-3, contextmenu

I have create a custom contextMenu using AS3 and can apply that to the stage. Any movie clip I place onto the stage does not inherit the contextMenu from the stage, i.e. they display the default contextMenu.

How do I apply my custom contextMenu to every child in my application?

[edit]

This is a simplified version of what I have in my main.as file:

```
var my_menu:ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
my_menu.hideBuiltInItems();

var my_copyright = new ContextMenuItem("Copyright - 2012");
my_copyright.enabled = false;
my_copyright.separatorBefore = true;

my_menu.customItems.push(my_copyright);

stage.contextMenu = my_menu;
```

If I right-click on the stage then I get the copyright. If I add a movieclip (or anything else) to the stage then right-click on that, then I get the default context-menu.

[edit]

I have found the problem, and fixed it. I was adding a background image using stage.addChildAt(mc, 0);. For some reason this removes the context menu. Placing the child at 1 fixes this and allows everything to inherit the contextMenu.

Before: http://richard.parnaby-king.co.uk/examples/stackoverflow/stackoverflow.swf

After: http://richard.parnaby-king.co.uk/examples/stackoverflow/stackoverflow-after.swf

I am changing the purpose of the bounty - can someone explain WHY this happens!?

Comment: can you share your context menu code?

Comment: @theButler I have added sample code.

Comment: How are you adding a contextMenu to the stage? I get a "Error #2071: The Stage class does not implement this property or method." when trying that. Also, is main.as your document class?

Comment: I have an empty fla file (using flash cs4) and set the document class to main.as. In the constructor (`public function Main(){/*..*/}`) I have the above code (with the appropriate includes). I have also attempted putting the code into the timeline, but I had to change the last line to `contextMenu = my_menu;`. In both attempts I get the content menu on the stage; but when I add a child object (for example a movieclip from my library) the child does not inherit the context menu.

Comment: Hmm, weird... I can't reproduce this at all. What happens if you explicitly change the context menu of a child? Does that work as expected?

Comment: @PixelElephant If I explicitly change the child context menu then it works fine.

Comment: I have found the problem, and fixed it. I was adding a background image using `stage.addChildAt(mc, 0);`. For some reason this removes the context menu. Placing the child at 1 fixes this and allows everything to inherit the contextMenu. I am changing the purpose of the bounty - can someone explain WHY this happens!?

Comment: I still don't know how you're adding a contextMenu to the stage - as per http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html you can't.

Comment: I think I was doing that in a different part of my program. I wonder why it allowed me to put it on stage then, but not on my main.as (as per documentation)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so after a bit of testing this is what I have. I can't say it's that definitively, as flash doesn't give the events for right-click, so it's only a guess, but it seems to hold up.

*On a side note, you can't add a context menu to the stage, it won't allow it, so the lowest item you can add it to is the document class*

When you right-click on a DisplayObject, it'll look for a ContextMenu on that object. It it doesn't find one, it'll continue on up the hierarchy for that object looking for one, stopping when it finds one. Something like this:

```
stage
    - document (has context menu1)
        - parent (has context menu2)
            - child
        - parent2
```

In this example, if you right click on `child`, there's no menu, so it looks to `parent`. Here it finds `context menu2` so it shows that. However if you right-click on `parent2`, there's no menu, so it looks to `document` and here it finds `context menu1`.

There seems to be a bit of a hack though when you right-click somewhere else on the stage (i.e. somewhere with no graphics). In this case, as the stage can't have a `ContextMenu` (or at least you can't set one), it seems to decide to use the context menu of the child at depth 0 (normally the document class).

When you added your background image at depth 0, you were bumping up your document class to depth 1. Your hierarchy now looks something like this:

```
stage
    - bg
    - document (has context menu1)
        - parent (has context menu2)
            - child
        - parent2
```

I'm assuming you're adding your context menu to the document class (in this example `context menu1`), so unless your document class has some graphics in it, your event would search up to the stage, find no context menu, then try to look for the context menu of child 0 - in this case `bg` which doesn't have one.

You can test this by drawing something in the `graphics` object of your document class (or clicking on one of the nested elements). If you right click on the graphics, you'll see your custom menu, even though `bg` is at depth 0. Alternatively, you can add another menu to `bg` to see what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your why really is subjective to what else you add into the stage & their order.

I could quote 2 points from the [adobe live docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#addChildAt%28%29) relating to the same :

---

> An index of 0 represents the back (bottom) of the display list for
>   this DisplayObjectContainer object.

---

> If you specify a currently occupied index position, the child object
>   that exists at that position and all higher positions are moved up one
>   position in the child list.

---

I think if you properly analyse all that is added onto the stage, you yourself might get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

try changing `stage.contextMenu = my_menu;` to just `contextMenu = my_menu;`

Comment: I should have specified, the way I do it is I put my context menu code into a public function in my document class, then I call that function in the first frame on the timeline. I don't know if this matters or not, but I always put my timeline code on a separate layer, and make that the top-most layer. This doesn't sound much different than what you've been trying, but sometimes Flash can be weird like that.